# Stopwatch usage in multiple methods

Tags: performance, c#-4.0, stopwatch

We are looking to utilize a stopwatch to help monitor performance throughout an application. The question I have is specifically the best way to implement it in multiple locations (or the pros/cons of one way over the other). As far as I'm aware we could do 1 of 2 ways.

Option 1: Create a new stopwatch within each Method.

*Time provided would be method's run time. If Function 3 was called by Function 2 & an outside function (one I wasn't monitoring), it would be listed twice with no indication of which was called via Function 2.*

Option 2: Create a single stopwatch in the primary Method & pass it to all submethods.

*Time provided would be a running time, thereby knowing how long it takes me to get to a specific method (ex. it would show it takes 2 sec to get to function 3, but function 3 doesn't complete until 25 seconds). It would only display times for methods called via my chain (with stopwatch being passed).*

Example Structure:

- SaveButtonClick --> Function 1
- Function 1 --> Function 2

  - Function 2 --> Function 3
- Function 1 --> Function 4

Comment: you know there are code profilers right? just saying that would make your life easier :)

Comment: Option 1 timing output: 
  SaveButtonClick = 21s, 
  Function 1 = 18s, 
  Function 2 = 13s, 
  Function 3 = 12s, 
  Function 4 = 3s
_Have to be aware of chain path to know that Save/Fun1/Fun2 aren't taking long. Need look @end of chain 4time length & work back_

Option 2 timing output: 
  SaveButtonClick = Starts 0s / Completes 21s, 
  Function 1 = Starts 3s / Completes 18s, 
  Function 2 = Starts 5s / Completes 18s, 
  Function 3 = Starts 6s / Completes 18s, 
  Function 4 = Starts 18s / Completes 21s
_Seeing start time jump from function 3 to 4 indicates time sink is function 3_

Comment: Xander, thanks but we can't introduce that into our Production code. Utilizing stopwatch is permitted though.